# bootstrap notifications on homepage

Tags: notifications, bootstrap-4

I want to show notifications of data inserted on the homepage of dashboard.

Dashboard has three pages of data insertion. I want to display information of data insertion on homepage.

```html
   
<div class="content">      

    <div class="alert alert-info">
    
        <span id = "t1">
            <b> Task1 - </b> This is a regular notification made with ".alert-info"</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
    
        <span id = "t2">
            <b> Task 2 - </b> This is a regular notification made with ".alert-success"</span>
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    
        <span id = "t3">
            <b> task 3 - </b> This is a regular notification made with ".alert-danger"</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want please elaborate!!!

Comment: i just want data insertion notification on my home page div

Comment: some thing like this echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> ';
echo 'alert("message successfully Inserted")';//but here i want to give if of certain label of madesignin page
echo ' location.href="madesignin.php"';

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Materialize Toasts](https://materializecss.com/toasts.html) to popup an information box when a data is successfully added.
I think bootstrap only provides a css information box