# retreive timestamp from mysql table field

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a log table in mysql fields names are table name , update_time update_time has timestamp . now i want to select the max update_time against certain tbl name

```js
<?php

      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$mysqltime = $con->query("SELECT Max(update_time ) FROM log_tbls WHERE table_name = 'abc'");
$timestamp = strtotime($mysqltime);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

?>
```

i have error strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Comment: And what is inside `$mysqltime` then? Var_dump it

Comment: I think $timestamp = strtotime($mysqltime->update_time);

Comment: You have to indicate column to select like "SELECT Max(update_time) AS update_time  FROM log_tbls WHERE table_name = 'abc' LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $mysqltime = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Max(update_time) as updateTime FROM log_tbls WHERE table_name = 'abc'");
  $m = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqltime);
  $timestamp = strtotime($m['updateTime']);
  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

?>
```

Comment: could u look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549300/bootstrap-notifications-on-homepage?noredirect=1#comment88216618_50549300

Comment: could u look at this question i am still stuck on displaying image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636430/get-mime-type-of-image?noredirect=1#comment88283247_50636430