# get mime type of image

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]i have create a field mime_type in table with datatype varchar(20). now i want to save mime type by using code

```js
$imgdata = base64_decode($arrayA[7]);

$f = finfo_open();

$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

arrayA[7] is where image store , after this mime_type is save in the table as

[image]

it does not display image

Comment: increase mime_type column length. your column length is 20

Comment: your code is fine. open database and change mime_type length because `base64_decode` image in 64 characters and you need varchar(255) length in this case

Comment: what do you mean by image is stored? How do you store it inside array?

Comment: @BilalAhmed no it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Below function returns the MIME content type for a file, where `$filename` is path to the file.

```
string mime_content_type (string $filename)
```

Let's say we have below code,

```
echo mime_content_type('php.gif')
```

Output will be **`image/gif`**

**UPDATE**

[finfo-buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php) this will help you in your case.

Comment: u meant like $mime_type = string mime_content_type ( string arrayA[7] )

Comment: but my image file is save in array from insert form

Comment: Your code looks good, increase mime_type content length and try

Comment: does not understand u. above some one suggested to increase field length i did it but same problem

Comment: what is there in $arrayA[7]? it should be string value

Comment: i have also try another thing if do not create another field for mime type and try to get mime type from select from the same field it will give result like shown in above figure

Comment: then you should get it, what is php version?